# Setting default values for CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on my first project with CoreData and I have the data model setup.

I have a tableview with an Add button that triggers an alert and lets the user enter a string:

```
func handleAdd() {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Company", message: "Add a new company", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
        [unowned self] action in
        
        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
            let newCompany = textField.text else {
                return
        }
        
        self.save(name: newCompany)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)
    
    alert.addTextField()
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

The string is added to an NSManagedObject array:

```
func save(name: String) {
    
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    
    // 1
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    // 2
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    
    let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                 insertInto: managedContext)
    
    // 3
    company.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

    
    
    // 4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        companies.append(company)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

All looking good so far except I want the app to launch with 5 cells already in place, then let the user add/delete as they wish. How do I set the 5 defaults that I want the app to launch with? I tried adding the below code to viewWillAppear

```
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    
    let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)
    
    company.setValue("Apple", forKeyPath: "name")
    company.setValue("Google", forKeyPath: "name")
    company.setValue("Facebook", forKeyPath: "name")
    company.setValue("Tesla", forKeyPath: "name")
    company.setValue("Twitter", forKeyPath: "name")

    self.save(name: "Apple")
    self.save(name: "Google")
    self.save(name: "Facebook")
    self.save(name: "Tesla")
    self.save(name: "Twitter")
```

At load time they all appear. Then when I navigate off the page and come back, they are added again. I know this is because they are in viewWillAppear and get called every time the page loads.

Apple's docs (Core Data Programming Guide) are a bit hard to swallow as a beginner but they do say

> For small datasets, create the managed objects directly in code.
>
> If you are using iOS or creating an application for OS X that is not document-based, you can add a check on application launch to determine whether a file exists at the location you specify for the application’s store. If it doesn't, you need to import the data.

I believe that second snippet is what I'm looking for in my case (correct me if I'm wrong), however I'm not sure how to implement it, so any help on how to set these defaults so they are added once (on load) and only once would be much appreciated!

Here are the initializers if they are of interest

```
var companies = [NSManagedObject]()
var container: NSPersistentContainer!
let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let companyEntity = "Company"
```

---

EDIT: code added to app delegate

```
    let vc = ViewController()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!
    let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "firstRun")
    
    if userDefaults.valueForKey("firstRun") == true {

        company.setValue("Apple", forKeyPath: "name")
        company.setValue("Google", forKeyPath: "name")
        company.setValue("Facebook", forKeyPath: "name")
        company.setValue("Tesla", forKeyPath: "name")
        company.setValue("Twitter", forKeyPath: "name")
        
        vc.save(name: "Apple")
        vc.save(name: "Google")
        vc.save(name: "Facebook")
        vc.save(name: "Tesla")
        vc.save(name: "Twitter")
        
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the questions: May the user delete any of the five default companies and are they supposed to be recreated? If both answers are `No`, register a boolean property `firstRun` with value `true` in user defaults. Then check the value in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. If it's `true` create the 5 default companies and set the value in user defaults to false. By the way: Your code in `viewWillAppear` except the save lines does actually nothing.

Comment: @vadian thanks, I tried this as best I could although I'm definitely a bit hazy on the implementation. I edited my post with the code I tried in applicationDidFinishLaunching, but I got an error - Xcode doesn't like binary operators with bools. Is my code on the right track i.e. what you were suggesting? Also, re your last sentence - you mean the setValue(s) aren't necessary? Thanks for the help, still getting the hang of this.

Comment: Also, as for the questions, the user should be able to delete any or all of the default 5 companies and add their own. And they should indeed stay deleted at that point, although I would like to have an "undo delete" feature as well but that's a bridge I'll cross when I come to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my comment and your – obviously failing – code after EDIT this is a suggestion how to implement `firstRun`:

First register the default value in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, the lines are necessary even if the default value has been changed meanwhile.

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

Then check the value (`UserDefaults` has a `bool(forKey` function) and create the companies. It's crucial that the code to register default values is executed **before** using the values.

```
if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {

    let defaultCompanies = ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook", "Tesla", "Twitter"]
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!

    for companyName in defaultCompanies {
        let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
        company.setValue(companyName, forKey: "name") // not keyPath
        companies.append(company)
    }
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

In your code you are creating **one** company and change the name value **5** times without saving this particular company. Practically that code does nothing.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand where I was going wrong with my attempt - however I tried your solution and I am just getting an empty table view.

Comment: Of course you need to reload the table view after inserting the objects.

Comment: I have tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad, should I be calling it elsewhere? I tried putting it after appending the companies array in the for loop in applicationDidFinishLaunching (after creating a reference to my view controller) with the same outcome.

Comment: The best place to reload the table view is after saving the context in the `do`  scope. Use the debugger or insert print lines to see what's going on.

Comment: So after inserting some breakpoints it looks like the 'do' is not getting called, which I assume means the if conditional is not being met?

Comment: Then delete the app and its contents in the simulator or add a temporary line to reset `firstRun` in user defaults to `true`.

Comment: I reset the simulator and ran it again, with vc.tableView.reloadData() and a print statement at the end of 'do'. The print statement is called but the table view remains empty.

Comment: It's quite hard to suggest without knowing the rest of the code. Are the companies created at all? Is the table view populated on the second run? Are the table view data source and delegate methods implemented properly?

Comment: Ok so I (think) everything is working properly now! I was still using keyPath when setting cell.textLabel.text and in my save function, so I changed them both to key instead of keyPath and now the app is loading with the default 5 companies. They're out of order (not in the order they are in the array of defautCompanies) but that's not a big deal. Can't thank you enough for your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using some kind of arbitrary `UserDefaults` value `"firstRun"` a better solution would be to simply implement de-duplication logic when you are attempting to insert new companies. Usually, an ID is used for this purpose. For example, a pseudocode explanation might look something like:

```
use id, table
if table has id {
    return table.get(id)
} else {
    table.insert(id)
}
```

With an actual Swift implementation, this will look quite different, but the idea remains the same. The following is an example from some CoreData code in my own project:

```
static internal func insert(at id: String?, into table: String?) -> Self?
{
    //unwrap managed object context and id
    guard let context = self.context, let id = id else { return nil }
    let tableName = table ?? self.entityName //the table name in CoreData
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Self> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id) //filter only results matching 'id'
    if let result = try? context.fetch(request), let object = result.first
    {
        //return the existing object
        return object
    }
    else if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: tableName, in: context)
    {
        //initialize and return a new object
        return self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }
    return nil
}
```

In my case, `id` is a String, but for you it may be an `Int` or something else. The point in the above code snippet is to use some kind of unique identifying value (`id`), check the table for an existing entry with that identifying value, and based on the result either 1) return the existing object or 2) insert a new object.

In application, this is a benefit because then calling `insert` multiple times will not create multiple objects. Assuming we have never inserted any item into the database with ID "abcd":

```
//object is inserted at "abcd":
let result = SomeModel.insert(at: "abcd", into: "tablename")
//since object at "abcd" exists now, this returns the existing object:
let result = SomeModel.insert(at: "abcd", into: "tablename")
```

Let me know if this answers your question or if you require any more clarification on this implementation. You mentioned that you are relatively new to CoreData, so some of these may be confusing.

Comment: Why is `id` and the return value optional? You are going to insert something at a distinct `id`  and you expect to get an existing object or a new one in an existing entity. Optionals are not for avoiding (design) errors at **compile time**.

Comment: What makes you think these optionals are for avoiding errors at compile time? They're not even for avoiding errors at all. The point is to unwrap once in a generic reusable function rather than unwrap every time the function is used. Feel free to unwrap `json["id"] as? String` every time you use it in your program rather than once in the reusable function.

Comment: @michaelfourre Thanks for the answer and the offer for clarification - There are definitely a few things in there that I'm not familiar with yet. I'll come back to this if I can't make vadian's solution work since I'm familiar and relatively comfortable with everything there.